# bootstrap carousel controls is not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am not expert with bootstrap , but the carousel auto-slide is working well
but when clicking on the carousel arrows (right/next-left/prev)
these controls not working

how to make it work?

the code

header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/glitch.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pace.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.vide.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

the carousel

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img width="960" height="384" src="img/slider1.jpg" alt="slider1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img width="960" height="384" src="img/slider2.jpg" alt="slider2">
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <img width="960" height="384" src="img/slider3.jpg" alt="slider3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing to include JQuery (needed by bootstrap), add following line in your page HEAD

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Here you can see a working](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/okzc238e/1/) copy of your same code

Comment: Hi , jquery is included in the header

Comment: but not 2.2.4 verion

Comment: I am using the most recent version

Comment: And which version of bootstrap are you using ?
Only bootstrap 3.3.7 is compatible with latest version of JQuery

Comment: I am using bootstrap v3.3.7 with jquery v2.2.4

Comment: ?? but if you told, 2 comments ago, that you were not using 2.2.4 ?
now with 2.2.4 and bootstrap 3.3.7 are working ?

Comment: Okey , not work even with jquery 2.2.4 or latest version

Comment: post full code, because your code in a "correct" page is working fine

Comment: I edited the question and added the header part to check it :))

Comment: it's impossible to check, all your references are local; the order (jquery before bootstrap) seems to be ok, any other check are not possible.
Are you logging some errors in browser's console running your page?

Comment: yes -http://localhost/dashboard/img/videoframe.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I fixed the error and still the same problem - I'll help you
after clicking the arrow (right or left) the URL path converted to URL path/#carousel-example-generic

Comment: I am also encountering the same problem recently. Did you get any solution @Ahmed-Mohsen?
I am also using Jquery 2.2.3 V and Bootstrap 3.3.6V. Any suggestion on this?
I put bootsrap.js  after the Jquery.js